# Create a green triangle C++ DirectX

Tags: c++, winapi, directx, rendering, game-engine

so i am trying to create a green triangle but have absolute no idea how to proceed. I am absolutely new to DirectX and win32 world, and lost right now. I played around with creating ellipse code given by my prof. Here's the code to that. I understand this, but absolutely clueless about approaching triangle. I was thinking about making three joint straight lines but could not go far. Help!

```
brush->SetColor(D2D1::ColorF(red, green, blue, alpha));
rendertarget->DrawEllipse(D2D1::Ellipse(D2D1::Point2F(x, y), radius, radius), brush, 3.0f);
```

Where brush and rendertarget are defined as

```
ID2D1HwndRenderTarget* rendertarget;
ID2D1SolidColorBrush* brush;
```

Comment: First of all, you seem to confuse Direct2D with DirectX. They are not exactly the same. You can draw any shape in D2D by creating and filling an instance of `ID2D1PathGeometry`.

Comment: Hey @VTT, thanks a lot for responding. You're right, i was confused between them. I've been programming for two years, but supernew to this and overwhelmed with all this new  stuff. Could you please help me out with drawing filled triangle with ID2D1? I know it sounds like a stupid question, but i'm really struggling with this.

Comment: You should read [Path Geometries Overview](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee264309(v=vs.85).aspx).

Answer (score 2):

For Direct2D, you should look at these Windows 7 era classic Win32 desktop samples on [GitHub](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-classic-samples/tree/master/Samples/Win7Samples/multimedia/Direct2D). Direct2D is a 'vector graphics' or 'presentation graphics' library for drawing rounded rectangles, filled circles, etc. that replaces the ancient GDI API from way back in the early days of Windows. You can write 2D games in it, but since those are mostly just sprites it's probably not the easiest solution. The Direct2D/DirectWrite/WIC APIs are pretty low-level, so if you are target Windows 10 you should strongly consider using the [Win2D](https://github.com/Microsoft/Win2D) library for Direct2D programming.

For Direct3D 11, you should take a look at the [DirectX Tool Kit tutorials](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/Getting-Started). Direct3D is probably the better choice for game development for both 2D and 3D games. You can do a lot with the toolkit's `SpriteBatch`. If you want to work with 'raw' Direct3D, then take a look at `SimpleTriangle` on GitHub for [PC](https://github.com/Microsoft/Xbox-ATG-Samples/tree/master/PCSamples/IntroGraphics/SimpleTrianglePC) or [UWP](https://github.com/Microsoft/Xbox-ATG-Samples/tree/master/UWPSamples/IntroGraphics/SimpleTriangleUWP)